# Largest integer not expressible as $ax + by + cz$ for $x,y,z \geq 0$ in terms of $a,b,c$, assuming $gcd(a,b,c)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This was a generalization of a textbook problem. I apologize if this question is too trivial for here.

If we first consider $ax+by$ and assume $a,b,x,y \geq 0, gcd(a,b)=1$, then the largest integer not expressible as $ax+by$ (in terms of a,b) is $(a-1)(b-1)-1 = ab-a-b$.

The question is then generalized to ask the same question of $ax+by+cz$ under similar conditions ($\gcd(a,b,c)=1, a,b,c,x,y,z\geq 0$). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a pattern in my program, so any help is appreciated. I did notice many of the integers were equal to $ab-a-b$ (not necessarily (a,b)), though the patterns were not consistent.

Comment: The case $n=3$ is treated here:   https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/geomfrob.pdf   , but there is no simple formula in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's goes under the (more or less standard) name of "Representation problem", or "Frobenius coin-exchange problem".
You can get some insight on it [in this paper](http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/Opt/farkas.pdf) and [in this other one](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/frobnote.pdf).

Comment: "For d ≥ 3, the quest for general formulas has so far been unsuccessful" Huh, so the textbook gave me an unsolved problem. Well, thank you for saving me the time.

Comment: Is the textbook a first step to mathematical olympiads?

Comment: @Improve: not exactly, it is just to indicate that the problem is quite a though one. Does the downvote come from you ? If so what would have been your answer instead ? Why don't you post it ?

Comment: @Improve: I was asking whether .. you have a better answer

Comment: Sorry, I meant to reply to Anonymous to ask where the problem was from. I barely read your answer.

Comment: Pardon, I misunderstood your question, also because of the ( anonymous) downvote

Comment: It was from "A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory" by Joseph Silverman.